# "Could not find the image" error in Processing Android

Tags: android, processing

I am trying to open an image that is placed at path "sketchfolder/data/1024x768/gulli2.png". Its working fine on windows but its not working on Android and giving error. Here is the error:

> Could not find the image \1024x768\gulli2.png. FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Animation Thread Process: processing.test.exercise_5_3_noisechain,
>   PID: 11878 java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   processing.test.exercise_5_3_noisechain.Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain$Gulli.(Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain.java:112)
>   at
>   processing.test.exercise_5_3_noisechain.Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain.setup(Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain.java:37)
>   at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source) at
>   processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source) at
>   processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

The code I am trying:

```
class Gulli {
  Body body;
  float w;
  float h;
  float angle;
  PImage img;

  Gulli(float x_, float y_) {
    float x = x_;
    float y = y_;
    w = (float)(width*2.2/100.0);
    h = w/2;
    img = loadImage("\\1024x768\\gulli2.png");
    img.loadPixels();
    img.resize((int)w*2,0);
    img.updatePixels();
    angle = 0;
    makeBody(new Vec2(x, y), w, h, angle);
  }

  void makeBody(Vec2 center, float w_, float h_, float a) {
    BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
    bd.position.set(box2d.coordPixelsToWorld(center));
    bd.setAngularVelocity(a);
    bd.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
    bd.bullet = true;
    body = box2d.createBody(bd);
    PolygonShape sd = new PolygonShape();
    Vec2 []vertices = new Vec2[6];
    vertices[0] = new Vec2(box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(w), 0);
    vertices[1] = new Vec2(box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(h), box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(h/3));
    vertices[2] = new Vec2(box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(-h), box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(h/3));
    vertices[3] = new Vec2(box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(-w), 0);
    vertices[4] = new Vec2(box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(-h), box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(-h/3));
    vertices[5] = new Vec2(box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(h), box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(-h/3));
    sd.set(vertices, vertices.length);
    FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
    fd.shape = sd;
    fd.density = 4.0;
    fd.friction = 0.6;
    fd.restitution = 0.3;
    body.createFixture(fd);
    bd.allowSleep = false;
    body.setUserData(this);
  }

  void display() {
    Vec2 pos = box2d.getBodyPixelCoord(body);
    float a = body.getAngle();
    Fixture f = body.getFixtureList();
    PolygonShape ps = (PolygonShape) f.getShape();
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    rotate(-a);
    image(img, 0, 0);
    popMatrix();
  }
} 


import shiffman.box2d.*;
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.*;
import org.jbox2d.common.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.*;

Box2DProcessing box2d;
Gulli gulli;

void setup() {
//  size(1024, 768);  // turn on for windows
  box2d = new Box2DProcessing(this);
  box2d.createWorld();
  gulli = new Gulli((float)width*15.0/100.0, (float)height*95.0/100.0);    
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  gulli.display();
  box2d.step();
}
```

Plz help.... Thank you..

Comment: Where is line 12 of Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain.java?

Comment: sorry my mistake. i forgot to mention display() function of gulli. i have mentioned it now. plz check now. thanks :)

Comment: which line are u talking about? is there any error?

Comment: `(Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain.java:112)` This part of the error message means that the problem occurs on line 112 of Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain.java...oops, I typed 12 earlier...so which line of code is 112?

Comment: there is no line 112. The error is where i am loading image. the path which i have given is not working on android. but its working fine on windows

Comment: try removing the slash at the beginning of the path: `img = loadImage("1024x768\\gulli2.png");`

Comment: not working..........

Comment: Please post the real error message that you get. The fact that you claim there is no line 112 implies that the error message you posted is not related to the current issue.

Comment: bro if you can read the error is real and clearly mentioned

Comment: Exactly! The error clearly says the problem is on line 112 of a file named Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain.java. So what line of code is this? You have not yet shown the file Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain.java. And you have not clearly marked the line which causes the error.

Comment: Do you have knowledge of processing? "Exercise_5_3_NoiseChain.java" is shown in the code. Its starts from statement "import...." onwards till the end. There is nothing missing in my description. If you know processing then put this code in correct tabs and run it to see the error

Answer (score 0):

Your log shows a NullPointerException error, this means you are trying to point to a non-existent image. 
Try to include the entire path. And without the double slashes "//".
If you are working with URI formats, then it could be that the control doesn't support these formats. If that is the case, download the image first, and then load it.

Comment: that its because you are not placing a picture named "gulli2.png" in your "data" folder of sketch. you can use any image of small size for checking purpose. thanks for your answer :)